# Kendo grid update issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i'm new to Kendo Grid.Can anyone help me.In Grid if Data is not given onclick of update button validation is raised.but the row gets updated.Update shouldn't happen

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project.Models.EmployeeDetail>()
                    .Name("EmployeeGrid")

            .Columns(col =>
                {
                    col.Bound(p => p.EName).Width("15%").Title("Name")                      

                    col.Bound(a => a.Address).Title("Address").Width("15%");                        
                    col.Command(a => { a.Edit(); }).Width("10%").Title("Edit");

                    col.Command(a => {a.Destroy();}).Title("Delete").Width("10%");
                }
            )
            .Pageable()

            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add"))
                 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))


            .DataSource(source => source
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(4)                    
                .Model(a => a.Id(b => b.Name))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("EmpGrid", "Employee"))
                                        .Create(create => create.Action("EmpGridCreate", "Employee"))
                                        .Update(update => update.Action("EmpGridUpdate", "Employee"))
                                        .Destroy(del => del.Action("EmpGridDelete", "Employee"))

           )
                    .Events(e =>
                    {
                        e.Save("SaveDetails");
                        e.Edit("EditDetails");
                    }))
```

Save Event Code:

```
function SaveDetails(e)
{
   var result=true;    
   writeMultipleMessage("error", "", "EName");
var EmpName = $("#EName").val();
    if(EmpName ==""|| EmpName == null || EmpName ==undefined)
{
      writeMultipleMessage("error", "Please Provide Employee Name", "EName");
  e.preventDefault();
      result = false;
}

    else
{
e.model.EName=EName;
}

    writeMultipleMessage("error", "", "Address");
    var AddressDet=$("#Address").val();
    if (AddressDet == "" || AddressDet == null || AddressDet == undefined) {
        writeMultipleMessage("error", "Please provide  Address", "Address");
        e.preventDefault();
        result = false;
    }
    else {
        e.model.Address = Address;
    }      
        var Grid = $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        Grid.refresh();

    }
```

I have shown my code above
Update is Hitting Save Event.Row is updated though validation is thrown.Row should not get updated
Can anyone Suggest some idea.Thanks in Advance.Sorry if it is a repeated Question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that $("#EmpName").val() isn't valid to the row you are trying to update. You have to look in the DOM object for the Kendo Grid row for your Column value. We can use $(e.cell).find() to locate the column you need to get for that row.

Try your JavaScript like this:

```
function SaveDetails(e)
{
   var result=true;    
   writeMultipleMessage("error", "", "EName");
   var EmpName = $(e.cell).find("#EName").val();
   if(EmpName ==""|| EmpName == null || EmpName ==undefined)
   {
      writeMultipleMessage("error", "Please Provide Employee Name", "EName");
      e.preventDefault();
      result = false;
   }
   else
   {
      e.model.EName=EName;
   }

   writeMultipleMessage("error", "", "Address");
   var AddressDet = $(e.cell).find("#Address").val();
   if (AddressDet == "" || AddressDet == null || AddressDet == undefined) {
       writeMultipleMessage("error", "Please provide  Address", "Address");
       e.preventDefault();
       result = false;
   }
   else {
       e.model.Address = Address;
   }      

   var Grid = $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid");
   Grid.refresh();

}
```

Here is Kendo UI's treasure trove of examples for the Kendo UI Grid for further assistance:

- [Kendo UI Grid Demo projects](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid) (MVC version)
- [Kendo UI Grid Demo projects](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/kendo-ui/grid) (HTML5/JS version)